# Help, how to deploy a xml package?

Tags: deployment, ant, package.xml

I am trying to deploy a xml file but i get the following error:

```
4.  objects/Account.object (Account.NbOppsOuvertesAvancees__c) -- Error: Invalid Field: Opportunity.RecordTypeId (line 1607, column 29)
5.  objects/Account.object (Account.NbOppsOuvertesBP__c) -- Error: Invalid Field: Opportunity.RecordTypeId (line 1628, column 29)
6.  objects/Account.object (Account.NbOppsOuvertesCE__c) -- Error: Invalid Field: Opportunity.RecordTypeId (line 1654, column 29)
7.  objects/Account.object (Account.NbOppsOuvertesCOAP__c) -- Error: Invalid Field: Opportunity.RecordTypeId (line 1681, column 29)
8.  objects/Account.object (Account.NbOppsOuvertesNX__c) -- Error: Invalid Field: Opportunity.RecordTypeId (line 1712, column 29)
```

here is my xml file used to deploy the package:

```
<types>
          <members>*</members>
          <name>CustomField</name>
      </types>
  <types>
        <members>*</members>
         <name>ApexClass</name>
     </types>
  <types>
          <members>*</members>
          <name>ApexPage</name>
      </types>
  <types>
          <members>*</members>
          <name>RecordType</name>
      </types>

  <types>
          <members>*</members>
          <name>FlexiPage</name>
      </types>
  <types>
      <members>*</members>
      <name>CustomLabels</name>
  </types>
  <types>
          <members>*</members>
          <name>GlobalPicklist</name>
      </types>
      <types>
              <members>*</members>
              <name>GlobalPicklist</name>
          </types>
  <types>
      <members>Account</members>
      <members>AccountContactRole</members>
      <members>Activity</members>
      <members>Asset</members>
      <members>Campaign</members>
      <members>CampaignMember</members>
      <members>CaseContactRole</members>
      <members>Contact</members>
      <members>ContentVersion</members>
      <members>Contract</members>
      <members>ContractContactRole</members>
      <members>Event</members>
      <members>Idea</members>
      <members>Lead</members>
      <members>Opportunity</members>
      <members>OpportunityContactRole</members>
      <members>OpportunityLineItem</members>
      <members>PartnerRole</members>
      <members>Product2</members>
      <members>Site</members>
      <members>Solution</members>
      <members>Task</members>
      <members>User</members>
      <members>UserLicense</members>
      <members>*</members>
      <name>CustomObject</name>
  </types>
```

what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package.xml file is perfectly fine, but your objects/Opportunity.object file is missing some data. Namely, there should be at least one [RecordType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_recordtype.htm) entry in file, as follows:

```
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
. . .
   <recordTypes>
        <fullName>My First Recordtype</fullName>
    </recordTypes>
 . . .
</CustomObject>
```

If you don't have at least one Record Type in the system for an object, you'll get this error if there's other references to the RecordTypeId field.

Comment: i looked to opportunity file and there is already a recordType there

Comment: <recordTypes>
        <fullName>Opportunite</fullName>
        <active>true</active>
        <businessProcess>Oppportunité</businessProcess>
        <compactLayoutAssignment>PresentationCompacteDOpportunite</compactLayoutAssignment>
        <description>Opportunité de Vente</description>

Comment: @MerabtiIbrahim In that case, it shouldn't ordinarily fail. Are you getting additional errors about Opportunity failing to deploy (e.g. some problem with the Opportunity object itself)? If not, then you may very well have encountered a bug, and you'll need to provide a dummy record type before deploying this package, or make two deployments, one with Opportunity, and then again with everything else.

Comment: yes, indeed, i got another error just before the errors i posted here, [sf:deploy] 3.  objects/Opportunity.object (Opportunity.Opportunite) -- Error: In field: businessProcess - no BusinessProcess named Opportunity.OppportunitÚ found (line 2063, column 18)

Comment: That this explain this errors

Comment: @MerabtiIbrahim Yes, you'll need to pull in the [BusinessProcess](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_businessprocess.htm) into your source so you can deploy it along with the Opportunity object.

Comment: Ok, thank you @sfdcfox, that helps a lot, i have many other erros waiting on the list but that enough for today.

Comment: just a last question, how to pull in this process ? by adding the <types>
         <members>*</members>
         <name>BusinessProcess</name>
     </types>                                               in xml file , because i thought that the process is already included in the object metadata ?

Comment: @MerabtiIbrahim I think so. You'll have to test it. I've never personally tried doing that.